# Creating multiple Boolean columns from a single factor column in an R tibble (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyr

I am working with a table that looks roughly like this:

```r
data <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  y = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "c"),
  z = c("info1", "info1", "info1", "info2", "info2")
  ) |>
  mutate_at(vars(y), factor)
```

In this table the x column is treated as an ID column. I want to turn the column y into multiple Boolean columns a, b, c, so that my new table is as below:

```r
dataf <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2),
  a = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  b = c(TRUE, TRUE),
  c = c(TRUE, TRUE),
  z = c("info1", "info2")
  )
```

I have tried using pivot wider but unfortunately I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `value` column to your dataset with a value set to `TRUE`, then reshape to wide using `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  mutate(value = TRUE) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = y,
    values_from = value, values_fill = FALSE
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>       x z     a     b     c     d    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 info1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
#> 2     2 info2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: When I run this I get an error message that says "Can't convert 'fill' <logical> to <list>."

Comment: Do you get this error on the example data or your real data?

Comment: On my real data which is weird since this works on the example, and the format of the data is the same.

Comment: The most likely issue is that you have multiple obs. or rows with same combo of `x` and `z`. As a result of such duplicates you will get a list column. You can drop `values_fill` to check that. If that is the case you should get a warning about that. A fix would be to make the obs. unique by doing `.. mutate(value = TRUE) |> mutate(id = row_number(), .by = c(x, z)) |> ...`. By adding the id column the combos x, z and id are unique. But you should still check your input data. Sometimes such situations arise because one dropped an identifier column.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you.